# Generating an article from an email in mediawiki

Tags: email, mediawiki

I would like to be send an email to an address that mediawiki can pick up and have mediawiki take it and generate a new page from it as a starting point.  More complicated stuff like categories can come later.

I have searched around on the web and not found anything obvious.

I have not developed against mediawiki before but am an able and willing developer.

Thanks for any assistance provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is this extension - [EmailToWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EmailToWiki)

It relies on a POP3 account being available and has been in Beta for a long time, but it may be a good start for what you want to do.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  And it's on the mediawiki website - weird that it didn't show up in my searches...

Comment: I found it while doing a manual review of all extensions the first time I installed MediaWiki. It took me a few attempts at searching to find it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have a daemon of some sort running on the server that picks up emails from an account (through POP protocol presumably), use the [Mediawiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API) to generate stub page.

Instead of a daemon, you could just have a `cron` job of some form.

Comment: Thanks - I knew the solution would involve the api in some way :).  I was hoping someone knew of an existing extension I could use/modify instead of having to do my own from scratch.  Not reinventing the wheel and all that.